# How to make a proper character design requisition?

Tags: character

I'm a game developer looking for artists to make concept art for my game characters/world and character design. (Yes, I'll pay them. No 'free advertising :D' stuff. This doesn't pay bills).

The thing is, I really don't know HOW to. I've got some contacts already but I don't have a 'how-to' to make the requisition. 
How do I ask for it? What do I send? Should I send reference images for 'something like that'? What kind of information would be nice to have when you are being asked for this?

I know that personality and background, both for the character and the scenario is a must, but what else should I send?

How would you, as an artist, like to receive such a requisition and in what format, with what content/things asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different aspects of your requirements.

### I. Style and concept.

- What are they about? Is it a fantasy game? Science fiction? Medieval?
  So you need to have a brief describing the overall story and premises.
- What type of character you need? Manga style? 2D-3D?, Highly detailed like Overwatch? A low detailed like Minecraft? (The spectrum is pretty board)
- On each character, what are their powers, what drives them? What is their story?

Some samples could help.

### II. Technical details.

What size in px, how many in between steps you need for each action? Which actions do you need (Walking, Running, Idle, jumping)?

That is the starting point.

So make a technical Brief, this way each character has a description chart that has the overall idea on what to expect of each char.

---

You can ask a designer to mimic some style. But probably you need to contact an artist that has already the style that you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for illustrators. Specifically, character designers.

Find one you like (based on their portfolio, affordability, etc) and then they'll sit down with you and ask you the questions they need to ask to do their job.